# Finding initial lower and upper bounds for bisection search for polynomial's roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, upper-lower-bounds, searching

When computing the nth root of a polynomial equation using bisection search, how does one find the upper and lower bounds of where to search?

Is there some kind of formula to bound the nth root to a polynomial equation should be?

Take for example cube roots.

Take the cube root of any number, where is it at least and at most?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All polynomials are continuous, which is essentially saying that their graph could be traced without lifting your pencil from the paper. So then, if $\alpha$ is a root of a nonconstant polynomial, $p$,* the polynomial should pass $0$ at $\alpha$ and take a value *near* $0$ for $x$ near $\alpha$. But we made the assumption that $p$ is nonconstant so $p$ must take small positive/negative values. But then since $p$ is continuous, for a given side of $\alpha$, in the neighbourhood of $\alpha$, it should have the *same* sign for all values it takes. It should be strictly negative on one side and strictly positive on the other. This is essentially the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

By testing values near $\alpha$, we can check their sign and determine whether $p$ is above or below $0$. The root, $\alpha$ must always lie between an $a$ and $b$, such that $p(a)$ and $p(b)$ have opposite signs. When we test a value, $c$, between $a$ and $b$, we can check its sign and discern whether $\alpha$ is in $(a,c)$ or $(c,b)$. This is the method of bisection. We are iteratively improving the bounds by testing values in the interval. I believe there is no general closed formula for the $n$'th bound without a recurrence relation, since it relies on you actively choosing which side of $c$ contains $\alpha$.

[image]

---

* Ignoring roots of even multiplicity; if that is the case, the function would not have a change of sign and the method of bisection would fail.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some kind of formula to bound the $n$th root to a polynomial equation should be?

If you mean a bound for the (complex) roots of an univariate$^1$ polynomial over $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) of degree $n$: there are many upper bounds, see for example [bounds on all roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_all_roots) in wikipedia.

These bounds are usually in terms of the polynomial's coefficients; just from the degree alone without any further knowledge you cannot give such bounds.

$^1$A polynomial in 1 variable.